# Where to define _SILENCE_CXX17_ALLOCATOR_VOID_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS macros?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am developing TCP/IP program using Boost.Asio but I am getting error :

```
note: see declaration of 'std::allocator<void>' 1>d:\hardware\libraries\visual studio 2017\x64\include\boost\asio\use_future.hpp(137): error C4996: 'std::allocator<void>': warning STL4009: std::allocator<void> is deprecated in C++17. You can define
_SILENCE_CXX17_ALLOCATOR_VOID_DEPRECATION_WARNING or _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
```

After reading the error I understood that I have define

`_SILENCE_CXX17_ALLOCATOR_VOID_DEPRECATION_WARNING`

or

```
_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
```

I define them once in Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional #using Directories but error is still persistent.

Then I #defined booth the macros in main file before including any header but still the error persisted.

Then I declared the macro in my per-compiled herder but the error still persisted.

I even tried 2 different boost packages. One installed with vcpkg package manager and one pre-fill binary.

MSVC 14.1 x64
Boost : 1.68 (x64)

Comment: Why "Additional #using directories"? You must define it in "Preprocessor Definitions".

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks your suggestion worked.

Comment: For sake of my knowledge can someone explain me why defining them in main file or pre-compiled header file didn't work. I had defined them before including any headers.

Comment: Because your define is probably to late and not seen by some #pragma once or include guard. Put it on top of your stdafx.h, it will work. (for me...)

Comment: @Quentin you should move your comment to an answer

Answer (score 4):

Just Turning off "SDL checks" is all you need.
Detail: property page of current project> 'c/c++'>'General'>'SDL checks'
(VS2019, Win10 X64; 2021/01/27)